# how is htmlspecialchars output supposed to be?

Tags: php, html, utf-8

if i do this:

```
echo (htmlspecialchars("andreá"));
```

i get

[image]

So i suppose if i do

```
echo (htmlspecialchars_decode("andreÃ¡"));
```

i will get andreá but instead i get

[image]

if i do

```
echo (htmlspecialchars_decode("andre&aacute;"));
```

i get andreá right, but i dont know what is happening can anybody help me?

Comment: What happens if you put `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` at the top of your file (what's the current value of this header)?

Comment: i added that heather and now i get andreá when i do `echo (htmlspecialchars("andreá"));`shouldt i get andrea&acute? @Rob W

Comment: No. See Frits' answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`htmlspecialchars` escapes only some characters: `<`, `>`, `"`, `'` and `&`.

You problaby want [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/htmlentities)

Which will convert your `á` to `&#123;`

What you're seeing is `á` rendered in the wrong characterset (because it didn't get convert to a characterset-safe HTML encoding).

Comment: THanks, htmlentities will prevent me form html injection as htmlspecialchars too? if i use `echo (htmlspecialchars("andreá"));`i still get andreá not &#123; should i use the header Rob suggested above?

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` will prevent HTML injection. `htmlentities` will also avert encoding issues, but if you do encoding right you shouldn't have any issues.

Comment: so how can i use htmlspecialchars to prevent injection, but still show my accents? sorry I'm new with all these injection @Frits van Campen

Comment: Use `htmlspecialchars` but fix your encoding. You're likely either using ISO-8991 or UTF-8, make sure your entire encoding chain is one or the other. When you mix them you get what you're seeing now. As for how to do that is more complex than I can answer here. If you search for encoding and utf-8 you'll likely find something useful.